# What is good Armament and Protection for a Quadruped Mecha?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, weapons, bio-mechanics, mechs

I have been looking for real robot models for a long time to create a realistic mecha for my story.

I decided to model Peace Walker from Metal Gear and a quadruped robot with wheels that I found on YouTube a few days ago.
The problem is that I can't think of a protection system for its lower part ("navel"), which I see as very vulnerable.
I would also like a simple but deadly weapon system: Metalstorm, Explosive Drones, Rockets, etc.

Examples here:
[image]

[image]

Resume: What I'm looking for is that the mecha has a way to protect itself from attacks that come from below as small vehicles or robots. In terms of attack, I want a simple but very destructive mechanism, perhaps airlocks with explosive drones guided by a swarm AI instead of guided missiles?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For modern tanks, the bottom is also the most vulnerable part. So maybe your problem can't be properly solved.

Comment: What prevents a layer of shotgun shells or anti-personnel rounds from solving this problem?

Comment: How big is the mecha?  What weapons will "small vehicles or robots" be using to attack the mecha with?  What technology is available?  (And why would putting explosive drones in an airlock help at all - won't it just destroy the airlock and anyone in it?  For that matter, what definition are you using to distinguish an explosive drone from a guided missile?)

Comment: The mech would measure 13 meters in height, 25 in length and 12 in width, something like that would be its measurements. Small robots and vehicles could attack with grenade launchers, anti-materiel machine guns, and small rockets. We are talking about a technology from 2060 onwards. An advanced explosive drone has the advantage of choosing targets at will, waiting for a target at a specific place and time (either hovering or on the ground) and perhaps even going undetected.

Comment: When I said airlock I meant a compartment that can be opened to launch some drones, something like in the movie "Angel Has Fallen" (search youtube for "angel has fallen drones attack" to see what I mean). These compartments would be on its sides and it could slightly rotate its body while rolling on wheels, overwhelming its targets.

Comment: That helps - note that not everyone will read all the comments, so the additional information should be edited into the body of the question.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding! The question as asked has nothing to do with your crawling mechs. It just asks"what is a good protection and what is a good weapon". Include more details about what the mechs are fighting and defending against.

Comment: VTC:Needs Clarity. It's never good to ask what would be "best." That's subjective. You haven't explained the nature of any attack that we can use as a basis of judgement nor have you explained the technology level of your world. Armament is worse - that's entirely subject to the goal of the mech's use in its intended deployment. There is no "one" best weapon. You've explained none of that, so all the answers are just guessing and not actually solving any problem. Please remember, without a lot of details, brainstorming is off-topic (see [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]).

Answer (score 3):

A near-present-day solution?

You mount [EM-SHORAD turrets](https://www.defensenews.com/digital-show-dailies/ausa/2022/10/14/shorad-laser-weapon-will-stay-in-development-phase-longer-than-planned/) (or an analogous system) on its belly. Laser cannons of multiple tens (or, with the tech level you're apparently working with, hundreds or even thousands) of kilowatts are much better than a swarm of [suicide drones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loitering_munition) or an [active protection system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_protection_system). They never run out of ammunition as long as the mecha is operational, and they derive their ammunition directly from its power source, rather than from drones or hard-kill interceptors, which both run out of shots/drones, need replacements shipped to them at relatively great expense, and can potentially leave behind [UXO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unexploded_ordnance).

Sure, lasers need maintenance, but so do interceptors/drones/etc. And a laser can be optimized for many purposes besides self-defense — as a soldering iron for self-repair, as a less-lethal blinding weapon, for long-range signaling, having its wavelength changed so it can be a flamethrower against biological troops, as a rangefinder for artillery spotting, as a target painter for laser-guided bombs/missiles/etc., and so on and so forth.

However, if things are getting close enough to attack your mecha's belly, something has probably gone wrong. Much like with tanks, simply accompany your walker with infantry (whatever "infantry" means in this context; it doesn't have to be humans). The walker supports the infantry, the infantry stop the walker from being swarmed. The laser serves as both a last-resort defensive weapon for the walker and a support weapon for the accompanying infantry.

There's some relevant math for this. [Peace Walker](https://metalgear.fandom.com/wiki/Peace_Walker_(Basilisk)) is ~454 metric tons, and has a top speed of ~40 km/h. That's 28,024,691.4 joules of kinetic energy at top speed. Even assuming that it takes 1 minute for Peace Walker to reach that speed (and I bet it's faster), that means its internal power source must put out at least 467,078.19 watts of energy. That can refill the capacitors for such a laser in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

**Ball turrets!**

[image: robot with ball turrets]

[ball turret image source](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/a-ball-turret-gunner-of-a-b17-flying-fortress-warbird--365776800966728855/)

The problem you note is the same as that encountered for the B17.  The solution: ball turrets!   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_turret    These cunningly placed gun emplacements allow coverage of the ventral surface.  They are themselves notoriously vulnerable to attack, as they are very much hanging in the breeze.

I have placed 2 on your robot as a suggestion.  You could place them farther forward for a different aesthetic.  I am concerned one in front and one in back might result in the ball turrets shooting each other which you never want.

Comment: You need to add a larger cannon to go between them in case they need more fire power

Comment: @Thorne - I felt the same way but worried that might be in poor taste.

Comment: Na that ship already set sail......

Comment: +1 just for having the chutzpah to suggest what easily 50% of the human population knows to be a dangerous and often abused weapon.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what sort of Tech-Level your Mecha is dealing with, it's hard to answer.

However, to protect the lower glacis, I'd go with a Hard-Kill Active Protection System like Trophy, but futurized a little to include the capability of dealing with multiple incoming rounds.

Looking at the Image you've posted - the first thing that popped to mind is a RailGun type system - the big long barrel on the back is screaming 'Mobile Artillery/Fire support' at me.

Answer (score 0):

**Slaughterbots**

A giant mech is a walking target with many weak spots. Damage the joints and it can't move anymore. It's a giant mobile weapon platform.

The best defence is a drone swarm

[image]

A cloud of small explosive drones surround the mech protecting it and hunting down any threats to it.

Missiles get intercepted and detonated before the can reach the target. Drones fly inside tanks and detonate. Snipers and infantry are hunted down allowing the mech to move slowly unmolested.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-2tpwW0kmU

Answer (score 0):

## **Armour**

You are worried about things hitting the walker from below? Slap some armour on there! Heavy armor makes shells and bullets and broadswords go plink plink and do zero damage.

Put armor on the legs and joints too. Those are the real weak parts. Trust me. I play Halo 3 on the highest difficulty.

What kind of armour you ask? Whatever they put on tanks and armored people carriers and battleships. Carbon fibre, Graphite, Kevlar, or good ol' metal. Metal is tough stuff. It was made famous by James Cameron in Terminator 2.

[image]

## Weapons

There are loads of weapons you could put on the mech. Piddly machine guns. Autocannons. Big battle tank guns. Even bigger battleship guns. Check it out.:

[image: pew pew pew]

Those guns are about 20 metres long. It would stick out the top like long guns in Zoids.

[image]

The choice of weapon will depend on what the mech is for. Do you want to murder swarms of fleeing civilians? Then go with a bunch of small rapid fire machine guns and half-dozen American flags. Do you want to explode underground bunkers from five miles away? Then use the big battleship gun and a single jumbo-size American flag. Do you want to breach the walls of Troy. Then go with the old reliable:

[image]